# akka simple cluster with two seed nodes

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I'm using akka cluster 2.3.6

I compiled two separated jars and inside I have main class

```
   val configuration = ConfigFactory.load()
    val bucket = configuration.getString("bucket")
    val system = ActorSystem(bucket,configuration)
    val resultDispatcherActor = system.actorOf(Props(new MyActor))
```

I'm running two separate jars:

```
java -Dconfig.file=poc.conf -jar poc.jar
```

where my poc.conf is the following:

```
akka {
  loglevel = INFO
  stdout-loglevel = INFO  
  event-handlers = ["akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger"]

  actor {    
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
       }
  remote{
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]    
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off

    netty.tcp {      
      hostname = ""      
      host = "10.0.0.5"     
      port = 2551
    }         
  }
  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://myCluster@10.0.0.5:2551",
      "akka.tcp://myCluster@10.0.0.5:2552"]
     
  }
}
```

inside netty.tcp block each first application assigned to port 2551 and part 2552.

However when I start both jars, each of them prints the following log:

```
[INFO] [11/16/2014 18:43:53.890] [main] [Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [11/16/2014 18:43:54.739] [main] [Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://myCluster@10.0.0.5:2551]
[INFO] [11/16/2014 18:43:54.757] [main] [Cluster(akka://myCluster)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://myCluster@10.0.0.5:2551] - Starting up...
[INFO] [11/16/2014 18:43:54.848] [main] [Cluster(akka://myCluster)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://myCluster@10.0.0.5:2551] - Registered cluster JMX MBean [akka:type=Cluster]
[INFO] [11/16/2014 18:43:54.848] [main] [Cluster(akka://myCluster)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://myCluster@10.0.0.5:2551] - Started up successfully
[INFO] [11/16/2014 18:43:54.858] [myCluster-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15] [Cluster(akka://myCluster)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://myCluster@10.0.0.5:2551] - Metrics will be retreived from MBeans, and may be incorrect on some platforms. To increase metric accuracy add the 'sigar.jar' to the classpath and the appropriate platform-specific native libary to 'java.library.path'. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar
[INFO] [11/16/2014 18:43:54.863] [myCluster-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15] [Cluster(akka://myCluster)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://myCluster@10.0.0.5:2551] - Metrics collection has started successfully
[WARN] [11/16/2014 18:43:54.963] [myCluster-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-6] [Remoting] Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://myCluster@10.0.0.5:2552]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: Connection refused: /10.0.0.5:2552
[INFO] [11/16/2014 18:43:54.972] [myCluster-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16] [akka://myCluster/deadLetters] Message [akka.cluster.InternalClusterAction$InitJoin$] from Actor[akka://myCluster/system/cluster/core/daemon/firstSeedNodeProcess-1#-86755168] to Actor[akka://myCluster/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the exact commands/settings you use to start each app ? It's simply saying that it can't reach `akka.tcp://myCluster@10.0.0.5:2552` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a port to the program when you run it. Your `netty.tcp.port` value defaults to `2551` in both cases.

An example of how to do this:

```
// 0 means a random unused port will be assigned
val port = if (args.isEmpty) "0" else args(0)
val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(s"akka.remote.netty.tcp.port=$port") //etc
```

Also, see the [cluster samples](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/cb05725c1ec8a09e9bfd57dd093911dd41c7b288/akka-samples/akka-sample-cluster-scala/src/main/scala/sample/cluster/factorial/FactorialBackend.scala#L37) for an example on how to do this.

Answer (score -5):

```
Make the seed-node to have the same port 2551 and specify under remote as below.

remote{
transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"

cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://myCluster@10.0.0.5:2551",
      "akka.tcp://myCluster@10.0.0.5:2551"]
     use-dispatcher = cluster-dispatcher 

  }
    cluster-dispatcher {
      type = "Dispatcher"
      executor = "fork-join-executor"
      fork-join-executor {
        parallelism-min = 2
        parallelism-max = 4
      }
    }
```

Comment: what's the point to use the same port on the same ip ? you're just hiding the problem that the second app instance is not accessible yet